# PHP CURL post form issue

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to post form trough PHP CURL.
This is the code I'm using: (Edited)

```
// This is some data in the $postfields, cut of version because there is a lot of fields

$postdata = array(
// Fields with a name starting with '_D:/' are hidden and set to one space char
'_dyncharset' => 'UTF-8', '_dynSessConf' => '-7211106995117675809', '/claims/BrgClaimFormhandler.value.firstName' => 'John', 
'_D:/claims/BrgClaimFormhandler.value.firstName' => ' ', '/claims/BrgClaimFormhandler.value.email' => 'johndoe@example.com',
'_D:/claims/BrgClaimFormhandler.value.email' => ' ', '/claims/BrgClaimFormhandler.value.telephone' => '555 783 4574', 
'_D:/claims/BrgClaimFormhandler.value.telephone' => ' ' // ....
);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.hyatt.com/hyatt/specials/offers/brgClaimPage.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Allow for redirects.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500); // Set the curl functions timeout.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); // Set the connect timeout to wait indefinitely.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Suspend output.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:\tmp\hyatt_cookies.txt'); // Save cookies to this file.


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1',
'Accept-Language: hr-BA,hr;q=0.9,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding: utf-8', 'Connection: Keep-Alive',
));

$j = curl_exec($ch); // Execute the curl command.

curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);

// Second request:

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Allow for redirects.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500); // Set the curl functions timeout.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); // Set the connect timeout to wait indefinitely.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'C:\tmp\hyatt_cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Suspend output.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1',
'Accept-Language: hr-BA,hr;q=0.9,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding: utf-8', 'Connection: Keep-Alive',
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------dLk3HzGmthYEYQtSHNptND; charset=UTF-8'));

$h = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $h;
```

Page is displayed in the output but only like when the page is first accessed no success about posting, no messages about invalid or missing fields.

When I post this data manually I get success, when I deliberately omit some data I get the form with messages about what required fields are missing.

But when I do it trough this code I just get the page displayed with form to enter data and no messages what is missing or is invalid.

Is there anything else I can set with curl_opt() or some other technique that I can use to get this to work?

Comment: just use chrome network tab and check the request, it contain all the fields and headers you need

Comment: I' using the Opera so I'm not used to chrome, can you give me more datails please? And how should I set those headers I find in this code?

Comment: try this https://coderwall.com/p/-fdgoq

Comment: Thanks but I did get this information by using Dragonfly in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the site checks cookies. This process mainly consists of two phases:

1. when you visit the form page server sets some cookies
2. when you post form data server checks that cookies

So you have to reproduce this process in your script as well as turn cookies auto-handling on (by `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`/`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options).
This mean that you have to do two curl requests:

1. getting the form page
2. posting form data

BTW, `curl_getinfo()` should be called **after** `curl_exec` call.

Comment: Ok I have try it but now I get the page with bunch of strange characters. I suppose I have to set the encoding to UTF-8. How I do that?

Comment: I fixed encoding. You where right about curl_info() now it's status code 200. What you suggested looks OK and I tried that. But I'm still getting the same output, just form, not the post success or missing/invalid messages above the form fields, even after two curl requests. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @toni rmc Maybe. Without any details I can only guess. You have to update the code in the question

Comment: OK I will post it. I try to keep it short.